# mysql C connector unresolved symbols on Win2k8 but not on XP?

Tags: mysql

I have a visual C++ 2008 express project which compiles fine on Windows XP with mysql C connector 6.0.2. When I copy the project over to a Windows Server 2008 x64 machine, it gets a bunch of linker errors like "unresolved external symbol _mysql_server_end@0" "unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4" "unresolved external _mysql_real_connect@32".

Is the mysql C connector 6.0.2 known to not work with Win Server 2008?

(Note, the C connector is installed into the same place on both machines, and since I just copied over the project wholesale, it still has the correct libmysql.lib include. The interesting thing is that the errors I get on XP if I remove the libmysql.lib are not the same errors I'm getting on Win2k8, so that's what makes me think it might be an incompatibility...or maybe it's just because win2k8 is x64 and XP is x86?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was because I had installed the x64 libraries but the app was still being built as an x86 one. So when I installed the x86 libraries it started working.